# TypeError: AWS.SimpleDB() is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I'm trying to access AWS SimpleDB with JavaScript.
My code is the following:

```
<script src="https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.1.38.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    AWS.config.update({accessKeyId: 'mykey', secretAccessKey: 'mysecret'});
    AWS.config.region = 'us-east-1';
</script>
<script>
    var simpledb = new AWS.SimpleDB();
</script>
```

I'm getting this error:

> TypeError: AWS.SimpleDB() is not a constructor

I tried creating AWS.S3() object and it works fine.

What's a proper way to initialize and use SimpleDB with a simple JavaScript?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It does not appear that the more recent versions of the JavaScript SDK supports SimpleDB.  I inspected the JS Source of the library you are attempting to use and even their most recent version of the Browser SDK and neither have that functionality (access to SimpleDB).  Here is the list of services supported in the current SDK.  Please let me know if I'm misunderstanding:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/guide/browser-services.html

EDIT:
 It is not supported in the *hosted* version of the library, which is what you get when you link to their JS in the script tag as above.  There are instructions to build a custom SDK script that you would host that would then support access to SimpleDB.  See:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/guide/browser-building.html

Comment: I tried linking to both aws-sdk-2.1.38.js and aws-sdk-2.1.38.min.js. Are you saying both of them don't have SimpleDB support? I'll try to link to the AWS SDK library release from GitHub and let you know how it goes. Thanks!

Comment: Right, both of their hosted libraries (where you link to them on their server) do not contain SimpleDB support.  You will have to build your custom version via the instructions to get that included on top of the 15-18 default services.  Good luck!

Comment: @Lev those are both the same resource, but the second one is minified (ie. all extraneous spacing is removed for a smaller filesize).

Answer (score 0):

you can get your own version from here, using that version should resolve your problem, but before of building make sure you selected the aws service you want

https://sdk.amazonaws.com/builder/js/

[image]